# Defining factory methods in interfaces or abstract superclasses of the product class

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, factory-method

I have an abstract super class and subclasses inheriting from it.

Each subclass `MySubclass` shall have a `public static MySubclass CreateFrom(ISomething something)` factory method. The interface of its argument is the same for all subclasses, but the return type must of course always be the type of the respective subclass.

Can I somehow achieve this to have static factory methods following an interface or abstract superclass method definition without creating a separate static factory class for each single subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **ISomething** is always of the same (or at least a common) type, you could make the CreateFrom method of the superclass generic and Invoke the constructor of the inherited class with the parameter. Just make sure all your inherited classes have that constructor (Not sure but I don't think there is a way to 'force' a constructor pattern).

```
public abstract class SuperClass
{
    public static T CreateFrom(ISomething something)
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), something);
    }
}

public class InheritedClass : SuperClass
{
    public InheritedClass(ISomething something)
    {}
}
```

This way you can create instances by calling

```
SuperClass.CreateFrom<InheritedClass>(something);
```

Or you split the creation and initialization:

```
public abstract class SuperClass
{
    protected abstract void Initialize(ISomething something);

    public static T CreateFrom(ISomething something) where T : new()
    {
        T result = new T();
        T.Initialize(something);
    }
}

public class InheritedClass : SuperClass
{
    public InheritedClass()
    {}

    protected override Initialize(ISomething something)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can´t define static members on interfaces as static members belong to a certain class. However I can´t imagine of a reason to use this. You should ask yourself why you need such a functionality. Does a sub-class really have to instantiate itself or can the same easily be done with another independent (factory-)class?

Just create one simple factory-class with a generic parameter that indicates what to create.

```
class Factory<T> where T: new()
{
    T CreateFrom(ISomething param)
    {
        return new T();
    }

}
```

Now you can simply call it like this:

```
var myFactory = new Factory<MyClass>();
myFactory.CreateFrom(mySomething);
```

Comment: That would however require an instance of the subclass because the CreateFrom method isn't static. I think that's exactly what he is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to a different solution in similiar kind of requirement. In my superclass which happened to be an abstract one I required to create an instance of subclass to do something with it so I did the following trick:

```
public abstract class Element
{
    protected virtual void copyFrom(Element other)
    {  
    }

    protected abstract Elememt newInstanceOfMyType();
    public object clone()
    {
        var instance= newInstanceOfMyType();
        instance.copyFrom(this);
        return instance;        
    }
}
```

Now all my subclasses inheriting from Element class required to override newInstanceOfMyType method to give away instance of its type and then also override copyFrom method to produce a perfect clone. Now people might argue that why an abstract Clone method cant do the same job? Yes it can. But I required cloned instance of subclass as well as an empty instance(without copying anything from current) so I came up with this architecture.